# getServerSideProps can't run properly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to dive deeper into Next.js, and currently I'm in the `getServerSideProps()` function. I don't know why, it looks like this function isn't working/running, I use `console.log` and it doesn't display the log that I'm trying to display.

Here is my code:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Get({ results: query }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Check getServerSideProps</h1>
      {query.map((q, index) => {
        <div key={index}>
          <h1>{q.title}</h1>
          <p>{q.body}</p>
        </div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/?q=${context.params.query}`
  );
  console.log("CHECK");
  const datas = await res.json();
  return { props: { results: datas } };
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Here are the details of my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "doqmentnew",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "10.0.5",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: is your file structure like `pages/tester/[query].js`??

Comment: yeaa, thats my file, btw thanks for you comment, somehow i can get the array data, but can't display it to my map

Comment: can you try to hydrate data like this JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(<your data>))

Comment: you know what, i've found my own solution, but idk if this is right or not, but it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my answer, its all good btw, and the last task is to display the data, so what i'm doin is put the array (fetched data) into state using useState in useEffect, and display it like usual..

Answer (score 3):

`getServerSideProps` as the name mentions is a function that is run on the server. What are you looking at there is the client side console, which means that there you'll see any `console.log` that has been made by the client side version of the app. To see the `console.log` you want you should try and look in the terminal where you start the app. (where you run `yarn dev/npm run dev`)

Comment: You are correct! i've seen my console only in my terminal, but, did you know why i'm still can't display any data in my map? fetch working as espected btw

Comment: By just giving a glipse at the code have you tried adding the query param? what is the url you used.

Comment: i'm using this url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/?q=a to fetch data, but i think i know how to deal this think, i'm just need to pass the props and save it to state.